# Why two single square brackets side by side in R

Tags: r, na, data-cleaning, square-bracket

I am trying to learn data-cleaning with simple code.

My central question is: what is the use of two single square brackets side by side?

Here is `df` as an example.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, NA, NA), y = c(6:9, NA))
```

The following code is one of the many ways to replace NAs with, say, 99. And I think it's quite simple.

```
messy <- function(df, impute){
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
df[i, ][is.na(df[i, ])] <- impute
}
return(df)
}
```

```
clean <- messy(df, 99)
clean
```

1. But why do I need to use two simple square brackets to locate the NAs.
2. Why isn't it possible to simplify the code to be `is.na(df[i, ]) <- impute` ?
3. Is there any more efficient ways to replace NAs, such as using the apply family?

Many thanks for answering.

Comment: FYI, the dplyr package has a `replace_na()` package that does exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a very complex way of replacing `NA`'s. You can reduce the function to -

```
messy <- function(df, impute){
  df[is.na(df)] <- impute
  df
}

clean <- messy(df, 99)
clean

#   x  y
#1  1  6
#2  2  7
#3  3  8
#4 99  9
#5 99 99
```

You can use `apply` family of functions as well but they are not needed here since `is.na` works on dataframes directly.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is simple and fast! If I insist on using ```apply```, what should I do?

Comment: You can use `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), impute))`. This can be used with `apply` rowwise or columnwise as well.

Comment: Having said that, may i know why are there two square brackets in that line of code?

```df[i, ][is.na(df[i, ])]``` Thanks.

Comment: The first one (`df[i, ]`) subsets a row and the second one subset the `NA` value from that row (`is.na(df[i, ])]`).

Answer (score 0):

Here are three more ways to replace NA's with a tidyverse approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:3, NA, NA), y = c(6:9, NA))

#purrr 
map_df(df, ~replace_na(.x, 99))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     6
#> 2     2     7
#> 3     3     8
#> 4    99     9
#> 5    99    99

#transmute/across
df %>% transmute(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, 99)))
#>    x  y
#> 1  1  6
#> 2  2  7
#> 3  3  8
#> 4 99  9
#> 5 99 99

#transmute_if
df %>% transmute_if(is.numeric, ~replace_na(.x, 99))
#>    x  y
#> 1  1  6
#> 2  2  7
#> 3  3  8
#> 4 99  9
#> 5 99 99
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>